# Server2019 "rpc_s_server_unavailable 1722" Error

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2019, rpc

I have a new domain and servers are running on Server2019. I am trying to run a script to edit dns records on DC from another server. But I face with the the error above. I checked the solution tips but result is not positive. Here are some controls I made:

- DNS is working. dcdiag /test:dns been passed.
- Firewall is disabled.
- Antivirus is disabled.
- RPC/Kerberos/DCOM services is just like the microsoft recommends.
- Regedit setting are checked and same as microsoft recommends.
- Required ports are open and allows.

Any idea to solve the problem?